# Data posted through HTML form is empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

This was asked before but I couldn't find an answer that help in my situation.

I have two forms in one page.

Assuming that **first form** requires the user to insert whether name or email then press "Add" button, and **second form** displays a "Result" indicating that user has entered required data then press "Continue" button.

Thus, there are 2 "Add" buttons for name and email in the first form, and 1 "Continue" button in the second form that posts data (name or email) to the next page.

**The problem** is that the data posted to the next page is empty; neither "name" nor "email" is carried onto the next page.

I'm in a situation that I need to place two forms separated in the same page and I cannot combine fields and add buttons with the result and continue button under one form.

*Note: the following codes are sample only.*

**First form sample code:**

```
<form method="post" action="somepage.php">
  Name: <input type="text" name="randomname">
  <input type="submit" value="Add">

  Email: <input type="text" name="email">
  <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

**Second form sample code:**

```
<form method="post" action="somepage.php">
   <!--Result Displayed Here-->
   <input type="submit" value="Continue">
</form>
```

As I mentioned above, the data that should be posted to the next page always sent empty, as if there is nothing entered in the "name" or "email" fields.

How can I make the second form carry on / post the data that is submitted on the first form to the next page?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You see the problem here? `<form action="method="post" action="somepage.php">`

Comment: This code contains an error, but since it is only 'sample code' it's hard to say whether this is the cause. Question is tagged Javascript, jQuery and PHP, but those are hardly even mentioned. Where is the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, I have it correct in my actual code, I just messed out here. The problem still persists. @diggersworld

Comment: you tried adding `var_dump($_POST);` in somepage.php? what is it dumping?

Comment: can you also put the code you are using on `somepage.php`

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the second form, only the second form is submitted. If you want elements from the first form to also be carried on you will have to either combine your form or create dummy inputs in the second form that are automatically updated (i.e. onchange) to match the info in the first form. I'm not sure how you're implementing this, but it seems like you don't actually need to submit the first form anyway so just combining the two and adding some javascript to the add button would be the way to go.